# Didn't print out any letter?

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>

/// Glabal Handle
HANDLE StdHandle;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  StdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // Console window
  MSG Msg ;
  while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
  }
  return Msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
      if(wParam == VK_LCONTROL)
        printf ("LSHIFT");
      break;
    return 0 ;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

This code can be compiled with mingw32-GCC without any warnings and errors.

It should print out "LSHIFT" if the left control is pressed, but it didn't.

Why?

Comment: You missed one break in WM_DESTROY

Comment: @Digital_Reality Thanks, I edited. But it still not works.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't create a window, so it can't receive any window messages.

You'll typically want to create and register a window class (using `RegisterClass()` or `RegisterClassEx()`), then create an instance of the window using `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()`.

Comment: But I want to create a console window in `WinMain ()` :-)

Comment: If you want to detect keyboard input to a console window, then use standard console functionality. Trying to do it with the WinAPI would be needlessly over-complicated.